# how to normalize speed(frame rate) of thread in different phones

Tags: android, multithreading

I have been doing some work on surfaceview class in android.
there i have used "thread.sleep(50)" in my run method.But the game runs faster on some phones and slower on others.What can i do to normalize the speed or make speed constant across different phones.

Answer (score 1):

Yes FPS can vary device to device based on the device configuration(processor/camera etc). You can set your sleep time depending on FPS.

Comment: actually game is running slow on high end mobiles and faster on lower end mobiles

Comment: how can i make it constant

Comment: what if you remove sleep time for high end mobile devices. I think you need to tune your sleep time based on the current FPS.

Comment: how can i do it.Sorry i am a beginner in this field.

Comment: You need to try different sleep time for high and low end devices and see how it behaves. If different sleep time serves your purpose exactly then you can tune it accordingly.